# Get Datacenter using kubectl command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there any command in `kubectl` to get the data centre details,something like

```
kubectl get dc
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what is 'datacenter' in your context. If you are referring to a cluster, then `kubectl cluster-info` or `kubectl get nodes` may be what you are looking for.

If 'datacenter' is 'all clusters that this kubectl is configured to access', then maybe `kubectl config get-contexts` or `kubectl config get-clusters` is what you are looking for. (a 'context' contains everything needed to address a single cluster: the cluster name, the access credentials and the default namespace).

Comment: Good point re the first two commands. Concerning the context, it should be `kubectl config get-contexts` and `kubectl config get-clusters` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with "data centre details" but the biggest addressable unit in Kubernetes ATM is a cluster. All relevant info about the context you're operating in can be viewed and updated via the `kubectl config` command, see also the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#config).